# Bytebuffer wrap using ByteBuf

Tags: java, netty

I want to wrap `nio.bytebuffer` using `netty.ByteBuf` without making a new object, because I want to slice `nio.bytebuffer`. But `java.nio` doesn't have that facility like netty.

Comment: Java NIO does have a slice operation. What are you talking about?

Comment: With reflection you do what ever you want. You can even turn a ByteBuf into a ByteBuffer for the same memory, though if you can stick to the public APIs your code will be easier to support.

Comment: @EJP : agree.but not Returns a slice of this buffer's sub-region.Like 
 natty.slice (http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#slice(int,%20int))

Comment: @PeterLawrey : yes i can turn ByteBuf to ByteBuffer.. but not ByteBuffer to ByteBuf

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want [Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(ByteBuffer)](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html#wrappedBuffer(java.nio.ByteBuffer))

Comment: @user2004685 - the important part of the link (the name of the relevant method), is included in the post.  please remove your downvote.

Comment: @jtahlborn I have not down-voted it. Just categorized it as potential link-only answer during one of the reviews, requesting the essential parts of the link to be included in the answer itself.